# Rust loop performance same as python

Tags: python, performance, for-loop, rust

I was working on mandelbrot algorithm to learn Rust and I found out that empty 25mil(approx 6k image) loop takes 0.5s. I found it quite slow. So I went to test it in python and found out, it takes almost the same time. Has really python's for loop almost zero cost abstraction? Is this really the best I can get with intel i7?

Rust:

```rust
use std::time::Instant;
fn main() {
    let before = Instant::now();

    for i in 0..5000 {
        for j in 0..5000 {}
    }
    println!("Elapsed time: {:.2?}", before.elapsed());
}

>>> Elapsed time: 406.90ms
```

Python:

```py
import time

s = time.time()

for i in range(5000):
    for j in range(5000):
        pass

print(time.time()-s)
>>> 0.5715351104736328
```

**UPDATE:
If I use initialized tuple instead range, python is even faster than rust -> 0.33s**

Comment: Python was never made for speed.

Comment: I guess you didnt read the post... I am saying that python and rust has the same speed

Comment: it is still slower by a considerable amount. and as john points out, build with --release.

Comment: we should have call rust: Rust Don't Forget To Compile In Release

Comment: @Stargateur It would be really nice if StackOverflow allowed customizing the tags in such a way that when you use the Rust tag while writing a question, an inquiry of "did you run in release mode??" pops up, and you can't post the question before answering it...

Comment: @Stargateur Well not really. I was already impressed with my mandelbrot rust implementation performance compared to python (30x) without --release mode.  But comparing python&rust empty loops being equal can bring some uncertainty. I mean empty loop is really as raw as possible. Who could thought that optimization can help there? And who would thought that python with tuple iteration is faster than unoptimized rust?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're doing performance testing always build with `--release`. By default Cargo builds with debugging information enabled and optimizations disabled. The optimizer will completely eliminate these loops. On the [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=03ebf0af73a00573c268aaa28059eca3) it drops from 975ms to 1.25µs.

Let's take a look at the assembly on [Godbolt](https://rust.godbolt.org/) for just the loops, no timer:

```rust
pub fn main() {
    for i in 0..5000 {
        for j in 0..5000 {}
    }
}
```

[Without optimization](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/vjd6aa7cY):

```
<i32 as core::iter::range::Step>::forward_unchecked:
        push    rax
        mov     eax, esi
        add     edi, eax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp]
        pop     rcx
        ret

core::intrinsics::copy_nonoverlapping:
        push    rax
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rsi
        mov     rsi, rdi
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp]
        shl     rdx, 2
        call    memcpy@PLT
        pop     rax
        ret

core::cmp::impls::<impl core::cmp::PartialOrd for i32>::lt:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        cmp     eax, dword ptr [rsi]
        setl    al
        and     al, 1
        movzx   eax, al
        ret

core::mem::replace:
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rdi
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 12], esi
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 23], 0
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 23], 1
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + core::ptr::read@GOTPCREL]
        call    rax
        mov     ecx, eax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 16], ecx
        jmp     .LBB3_1
.LBB3_1:
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rsp + 12]
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp]
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 23], 0
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rip + core::ptr::write@GOTPCREL]
        call    rcx
        jmp     .LBB3_4
.LBB3_2:
        test    byte ptr [rsp + 23], 1
        jne     .LBB3_8
        jmp     .LBB3_7
        mov     rcx, rax
        mov     eax, edx
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rcx
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 32], eax
        jmp     .LBB3_2
.LBB3_4:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 16]
        add     rsp, 40
        ret
.LBB3_5:
        jmp     .LBB3_2
        mov     rcx, rax
        mov     eax, edx
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rcx
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 32], eax
        jmp     .LBB3_5
.LBB3_7:
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 24]
        call    _Unwind_Resume@PLT
        ud2
.LBB3_8:
        jmp     .LBB3_7

core::ptr::read:
        sub     rsp, 24
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rdi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 20]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 16], eax
        jmp     .LBB4_2
.LBB4_2:
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        lea     rsi, [rsp + 16]
        mov     edx, 1
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::intrinsics::copy_nonoverlapping@GOTPCREL]
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 16]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        add     rsp, 24
        ret

core::ptr::write:
        sub     rsp, 4
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], esi
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp]
        mov     dword ptr [rdi], eax
        add     rsp, 4
        ret

core::iter::range::<impl core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator for core::ops::range::Range<A>>::next:
        push    rax
        call    qword ptr [rip + <core::ops::range::Range<T> as core::iter::range::RangeIteratorImpl>::spec_next@GOTPCREL]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp], eax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], edx
        mov     edx, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp]
        pop     rcx
        ret

core::clone::impls::<impl core::clone::Clone for i32>::clone:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rdi]
        ret

<I as core::iter::traits::collect::IntoIterator>::into_iter:
        mov     edx, esi
        mov     eax, edi
        ret

<core::ops::range::Range<T> as core::iter::range::RangeIteratorImpl>::spec_next:
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     rsi, rdi
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rsi
        mov     rdi, rsi
        add     rsi, 4
        call    core::cmp::impls::<impl core::cmp::PartialOrd for i32>::lt
        mov     byte ptr [rsp + 31], al
        mov     al, byte ptr [rsp + 31]
        test    al, 1
        jne     .LBB9_3
        jmp     .LBB9_2
.LBB9_2:
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 32], 0
        jmp     .LBB9_7
.LBB9_3:
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
        call    core::clone::impls::<impl core::clone::Clone for i32>::clone
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 12], eax
        mov     edi, dword ptr [rsp + 12]
        mov     esi, 1
        call    <i32 as core::iter::range::Step>::forward_unchecked
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 8], eax
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
        call    qword ptr [rip + core::mem::replace@GOTPCREL]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 4], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 4]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 36], eax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 32], 1
.LBB9_7:
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 32]
        mov     edx, dword ptr [rsp + 36]
        add     rsp, 40
        ret

example::main:
        sub     rsp, 72
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 24], 0
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 28], 5000
        mov     edi, dword ptr [rsp + 24]
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rsp + 28]
        call    qword ptr [rip + <I as core::iter::traits::collect::IntoIterator>::into_iter@GOTPCREL]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 16], eax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 20], edx
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 20]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsp + 16]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 32], ecx
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 36], eax
.LBB10_2:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + core::iter::range::<impl core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator for core::ops::range::Range<A>>::next@GOTPCREL]
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 32]
        call    rax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 44], edx
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 40], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 40]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB10_5
        jmp     .LBB10_13
.LBB10_13:
        jmp     .LBB10_6
        ud2
.LBB10_5:
        add     rsp, 72
        ret
.LBB10_6:
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 48], 0
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 52], 5000
        mov     edi, dword ptr [rsp + 48]
        mov     esi, dword ptr [rsp + 52]
        call    qword ptr [rip + <I as core::iter::traits::collect::IntoIterator>::into_iter@GOTPCREL]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 8], eax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 12], edx
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 12]
        mov     ecx, dword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 56], ecx
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 60], eax
.LBB10_8:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rip + core::iter::range::<impl core::iter::traits::iterator::Iterator for core::ops::range::Range<A>>::next@GOTPCREL]
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 56]
        call    rax
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 68], edx
        mov     dword ptr [rsp + 64], eax
        mov     eax, dword ptr [rsp + 64]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB10_11
        jmp     .LBB10_14
.LBB10_14:
        jmp     .LBB10_12
        ud2
.LBB10_11:
        jmp     .LBB10_2
.LBB10_12:
        jmp     .LBB10_8

__rustc_debug_gdb_scripts_section__:
        .asciz  "\001gdb_load_rust_pretty_printers.py"

DW.ref.rust_eh_personality:
        .quad   rust_eh_personality
```

[With optimization](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/reWxYqb5o)

```
example::main:
        ret
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see the difference now. Why is there such difference? Doesnt rust on 'cargo run' compile anyway?

Comment: While this is a great answer for the Rust half of things, I think a fuller answer could mention how `for` loops are implemented in CPython: unlike a while loop, all of the iteration and bounds checking for a bare for loop like this are done in `C`, rather than directly through Python bytecode

Comment: @kcsquared It's hard to cover the Python side of things with a well-rounded answer because the OP expected Python to be slower than Rust, and it indeed turns out to be slower. (It's impossible to say how much slower because Rust optimizes away the whole iteration in release mode.) One could show in varying levels of detail how CPython is faster than an imaginary naive implementation where `for` desugared into a `while`, but what would be the point? Note that this is in no way a criticism of Python, I actually *like* it. :)

Comment: @user4815162342 That's true. Although my suggestion came from ignorance about the Rust error and trying to answer 'Why is Python's `for` faster than expected' rather than 'Why is this Rust code much, much slower than it should be', I've also since found links to [Stackoverflow posts already providing exactly my requested explanation about Python.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869229/why-is-looping-over-range-in-python-faster-than-using-a-while-loop), so a link to those is better than repeating their answers.

Comment: @Martin Compilation just means taking the source code and mapping it to some other target, in Rust that target being a native binary. This is totally orthogonal to the optimizations such compilation might make - you need to ask for them with `--release`.

Answer (score 4):

**Python vs. Rust (seconds vs. picoseconds) - performance definitely not the same**

CPython 3.8.10 / rustc 1.55.0 (running on Linux guest hosted by 10+ yo mac).

Adding some steps to the Rust code to try to ensure the loops don't get optimized into oblivion. I figure the best way to ensure this is to receive user input to initialize some variables, update those variables in the loops, and print to standard output. It's still going to optimize it, but at least the loops don't just evaporate.

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::env::args;
use timeit::timeit_loops;
use timeit::timeit;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>>
{
    let a = args().skip(1).map(|s| s.parse())
                  .collect::<Result<Vec<usize>, _>>()?;
    let n = a[0];
    let m = a[1];
    let mut d = 0;
   
    // timeit increases the nesting of the loops to get enough
    // samples of the timed code to calculate a good average.
    // The number of loops timeit takes for sampling is included 
    // in the output.
    timeit!({
        for i in 0..5000 {
            d += m * i;
            for j in 0..5000 {
                d += n * j;
            }
        }
    });
    println!("d: {}", d);
    Ok(())
}
```

Output (average nanoseconds for each timeit loop):

```
$ cargo run --release -- 52 3
1000000 loops: 0.000029 ns
    :
```

The comparable Python code, set up to run 1 timeit loop - I don't have the patience to let it go for more. These nested loops are very slow on Python.

```py
import sys
import timeit

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = list(map(int, sys.argv[1:]))
    n = a[0]
    m = a[1]
    d = 0
   
    def loops():
        global n, m, d
        for i in range(5000):
            d += m * i;
            for j in range(5000):
                d += n * j;

    # The Rust timeit version iterated 1000000; Python is too
    # slow to let timeit run a fraction of that number.
    print(timeit.timeit(loops, number=1)) 
    print(d)
```

Output (results in seconds):

```
$ python loops.py 52 3
3.8085460959700868
    :
```

Running the Rust program debug build also beats Python: 811 ms vs. 3.8 s

Running the same program on PyPy 3.6.9 (Rust wins)

```
$ pypy3 loops.py 52 3
0.05104120302712545
    :
```

PyPy3 beats the debug build of the Rust program, but doesn't come close to the release version.