# How can I prevent code redundancy in Rust

Tags: rust

I am seeking to extend the pattern by utilizing default arguments in Rust as seen in previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24047686/default-function-arguments-in-rust) by someone which is using an "arguments" struct and the `From`/`Into` traits.

However, as you can see, the code clearly looks very redundant and adding associated functions to `Foo` struct would require more code for the `From`/`Into` traits accordingly.

```rust
type FileName = Option<String>;

pub struct BarArg {
    a: f64,
    b: FileName,
}

impl Default for BarArg {
    fn default() -> Self {
        BarArg { a: 1.0, b: None }
    }
}

impl From<()> for BarArg {
    fn from(_: ()) -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
}

impl From<f64> for BarArg {
    fn from(a: f64) -> Self {
        Self {
            a,
            ..Self::default()
        }
    }
}

impl From<Option<String>> for BarArg {
    fn from(b: Option<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            b,
            ..Self::default()
        }
    }
}

impl From<(f64, Option<String>)> for BarArg {
    fn from((a, b): (f64, Option<String>)) -> Self {
        Self { a, b }
    }
}

pub struct BazArg {
    a: i32,
    b: FileName,
}

impl Default for BazArg {
    fn default() -> Self {
        BazArg { a: 1, b: None }
    }
}

impl From<()> for BazArg {
    fn from(_: ()) -> Self {
        Self::default()
    }
}

impl From<i32> for BazArg {
    fn from(a: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            a,
            ..Self::default()
        }
    }
}

impl From<Option<String>> for BazArg {
    fn from(b: Option<String>) -> Self {
        Self {
            b,
            ..Self::default()
        }
    }
}

impl From<(i32, Option<String>)> for BazArg {
    fn from((a, b): (i32, Option<String>)) -> Self {
        Self { a, b }
    }
}

struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    pub fn bar<A>(bar_arg: A)
    where
        A: Into<BarArg>,
    {
        match bar_arg.into().b {
            Some(b) => {
                println!("FileName is: {:?}", b);
            }
            None => {
                println!("No FileName was passed");
            }
        };
    }

    pub fn baz<A>(baz_arg: A)
    where
        A: Into<BazArg>,
    {
        match baz_arg.into().b {
            Some(b) => {
                println!("FileName is: {:?}", b);
            }
            None => {
                println!("No FileName was passed");
            }
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo::bar(());
    Foo::bar(Some("bar.toml".to_string()));
    Foo::baz(());
    Foo::baz(Some("baz.toml".to_string()));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=46c2af71586b46f486df454eba57a028)

Is there any way to somehow implement these codes in a non-redundant and concise manner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't. Do not emulate features, especially when they have good (even better) alternatives. And do not abuse other features to emulate those features.

---

That being said, it *is* possible to make it less boilerplate-y using macros. An important point to note is: what if two parameters have the same type? this will generate conflicting `From` implementations. You have to make sure it either doesn't happen or you only allow omitting the last parameters. You can expose the parameters struct to allow more flexible filling.

The tricky part is that both for allowing all consecutive parameter sequences and for allowing only the last we will need TT munching. This is because `macro_rules!` cannot extract from the middle of a list, or even from its end. It can only match its start.

Here's a macro that only allows omitting the last arguments. It also always requires you to pass a tuple, so you pass `(1,)` instead of just `1`, for example. It is pretty easy to allow this, but I like the always-tuple approach because I feel it is more consistent (lifting the only-last limit is much harder, but possible):

```rust
macro_rules! impl_from_for_default {
    // Recursion stop condition
    {
        $struct_name:ident {}
    } => {
        impl ::core::convert::From<()> for $struct_name {
            fn from((): ()) -> Self {
                Self::default()
            }
        }
    };
    
    {
        $struct_name:ident {
            $($param:ident : $param_ty:ty,)*
        }
    } => {
        impl ::core::convert::From<( $($param_ty,)* )> for $struct_name {
            fn from(( $($param,)* ): ( $($param_ty,)* )) -> Self {
                Self {
                    $($param,)*
                    ..Self::default()
                }
            }
        }
        
        omit_last_param! {
            $struct_name
            [ ]
            $($param : $param_ty,)*
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! omit_last_param {
    // Recursion stop condition
    {
        $struct_name:ident
        [ $($first_params:tt)* ]
        $last_param:ident : $last_param_ty:ty,
    } => {
        impl_from_for_default! {
            $struct_name {
                $($first_params)*
            }
        }
    };
    
    {
        $struct_name:ident
        [ $($first_params:tt)* ]
        $param:ident : $param_ty:ty,
        $($rest:tt)*
    } => {
        omit_last_param! {
            $struct_name
            [
                $($first_params)*
                $param : $param_ty,
            ]
            $($rest)*
        }
    };
}

macro_rules! with_default {
    {
        $vis:vis $struct_name:ident {
            $($param:ident : $param_ty:ty = $param_default:expr),* $(,)?
        }
    } => {
        $vis struct $struct_name {
            $($param : $param_ty,)*
        }
        
        impl ::core::default::Default for $struct_name {
            fn default() -> Self {
                Self {
                    $($param : $param_default,)*
                }
            }
        }
        
        impl_from_for_default! {
            $struct_name {
                $($param : $param_ty,)*
            }
        }
    };
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f4b5c04c44d8f251979e264f5cd2a142).

Example usage:

```rust
with_default! {
    pub BazArg {
        a: i32 = 1,
        b: FileName = None,
    }
}
```

Comment: I could not think of a way to make this much possible using macros. Thank you very much.